# If $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff topological space, then for each closed subset $C\subseteq X$ and for each $x\in X-C$ there exist open sets....

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm trying to prove the following.
If $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff topological space, then for each closed subset $C\subseteq X$ and for each $x\in X-C$ there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $C\subseteq U$, $x\in V$, and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

So I've tried it many different ways and the way I'm trying to prove is by taking similar method to Tube lemma.

I can see that since $C$ is closed, it is compact...

Answer (score 1):

For every $y\in C$, choose open neighborhoods $U_y$ of $y$ and $V_y$ of $X$ such that $U_y\cap V_y=\emptyset$.

Since $\{U_y:y\in C\}$ is an open cover of $C$, which is compact, …